# filtering and ordering on custom fields in wordpress json api

Tags: json, wordpress

I have a custom post type of 'venues' and I want to use the JSON REST API plugin to select only venues with a certain 'Category' value ('CMJ') and then order the results by the 'priority' field. I am using the following URL to retrieve my JSON and it is not giving me the results I desire

`<siteurl>/api/venues/get/?page=2&post_status=publish&posts_per_page=6&thumbnail_size=medium&order=DESC&orderby=priority&meta_key=Category&meta_compare=LIKE&meta_value=CMJ`

This is giving me the appropriate CMJ venues but the output is not sorted. Also, for some reason the JSON returned only has a 'priority' field for posts where the priority has been changed from the default value of 0.

IT's worth noting that I am using this to implement a 'lazy-loading' feature, so I can't simply sort the data after json fetches it because the json query handles pagination and it would be a lot of effort to restructure the system at this stage.

I believe I can get what I want from PHP using the WP_Query class with arrays for the parameters since I am uncertain but think the order field would look for a meta_key field to sort on, and I have two different meta_key fields, can I use array in the URL to make this distinction or what?

In summation, is it possible to filter results on a custom field and then also order those results by a different field?

Comment: sorry if my post sucks, this is actually my first time posting on SO, feel free to request more information or just flame me for my inexperience

Comment: it looks like the orderby parameter can only take a few specific options (date, modified, title, ID, etc) http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/1/get/sites/%24site/posts/

so I'd have to figure something else out for sorting either way